# Can you play Xbox 360 games multiplayer on the Xbox one?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network, fable-3

Me and a friend live long distance and want to play fable and halo together co-op but I have a one and she a 360.  So I was wondering if the backwards compatibility would let us play multiplayer.  Any answer is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. An Xbox 360 game running on the Xbox One has full multiplayer support. From the Xbox One Backward Compatibility FAQ:

> Can I do multiplayer gaming with friends who are playing the game on
>   Xbox 360 or Xbox One?
>
> Yes. For games that offer multiplayer gaming, you'll be able to play
>   with others who own the title on Xbox 360.

Source: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/console/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq#56a2123e4a7b479c9154fb304386099e